# How can I increase the value of a cell number by 1, and copy from one sheet to the next sheet's next available row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Firstly, my problem is that I went onto google sheets and recorded a macro. However, I would like to adjust the value from a cell (e.g. C1) to when triggered this macro, automatically increase the value (+1). Hopefully, I could get it to work by the currentvalue everytime it increase by 1. (*x*+1) in this formula.

From that, the link attached to Cell C1 would load the list of information generated, copy and paste from the areas give (A6:B7). and transfer onto the next Sheet. However, I want it to copy and paste onto the next empty row.

Right now, it does copy and paste ONLY but it overwrites my existing data. And the number is not auto-generated, hence, I would be required to change the number page by page (e.g. 350 to 351) manually.

Currently, this is the code which was triggered based on google sheets:

```
"function Testin1() {"
  "var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();"
  "spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();"
  "spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('fixedvalue'+ '1');"
  "spreadsheet.getRange('A6:B7').activate();"
  "var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();"
  "spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();"
  "currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();"
  "spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Companies'), true);
  "spreadsheet.getRange('A7062').activate();"
  "spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet1!A6:B25').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange()," "SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);"
```

I hope someone could guide this first timer through this. I will definitely be confused by the jargons used, so if you could guide me through.

Comment: Please explain exactly word by word what you are trying to achieve. For example, you say you want to increase a value of a formula by one. But what is that value ? Provide more details . Example : I have a sheet with a name Sheet1. This sheet contains a value in cell A3 and I want to transfer this value to the last row of another sheet called Sheet2. Etc. If you provide more information, then you will help us understand your problem and eventually help you solving it.

Comment: @fraser Welcome to StackOverFlow. Below you can see an answer that somewhat addresses your question. As a friendly reminder, if this satiasfies your request, please do me the courtesy of clicking the accept button as it encourages folks to be helpful to questions like yours. Also, your actual code has a bunch of unnecassary quotes in it. I hope that's not what's really causing you issues. Hope it works out.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments and rating indicate, your question could use a little simplified structure as to exactly what you would like to accomplish. However, I'll answer the two questions within the wording of your post.

I made [this googlesheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gWnw9GbwPnafDatmQOTTC3_LDeQX-TaT9WqICcDoLrY/edit?usp=sharing) to illustrate the procedures below. If you create a copy of the file, you should be able to manipulate it and see how the code interacts with the file.

### Code to increment a cell value by 1

This procedure identifies a cell and will increase its value by one. Note that if a formula existed in this cell, it would be overwritten by the overall new value.

```
function runTheUpByOne(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const theCellAddress = 'C1';
  const theSheetName = 'sheetAlpha';
  var theCell = ss.getSheetByName(theSheetName).getRange(theCellAddress);
  theCell.setValue(theCell.getValue()+1);
}
```

### Copy Values To Different Sheet in Next Available Row

Unlike VBA, Google has a pretty reliable way of [getting the last row](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) of a sheet. So it's just a matter of [getting the values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), and inserting them using [set values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

```
function copyToSomeOtherSheet(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pullValues = ss.getSheetByName("sheetAlpha").getRange("A6:B7").getValues();
  
  var theDropSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetBravo");
  var theLastRow = theDropSheet.getLastRow();
  theDropSheet.getRange(theLastRow+1,1,
                        pullValues.length,pullValues[0].length).setValues(pullValues);  
}
```